# Не отправляется кнопка клавиатуры vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Пишу бота для вк, пытаюсь отправить кнопку, но не получается. Рад любой помощи.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import config

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = config.token)

session_api = vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def write_msg(user_id, message):
    keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
    keyboard.add_button('Первая кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY)

    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id' : 0 , keyboard : keyboard.get_keyboard() })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                id = event.user_id
                write_msg(id, 'Привет')
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
{'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id' : 0 , keyboard : keyboard.get_keyboard() }
```

Ключ должен быть строкой, а не объектом:

```py
{'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id' : 0 , 'keyboard' : keyboard.get_keyboard() }
```

Comment: Спасибо, верно замечено, но теперь выдает ошибку -
[912] This is a chat bot feature, change this status in settings

Comment: @Exodus Чтобы включить клавиатуры в сообществе, перейдите в "Управление сообществом" → "Сообщения" → "Настройки для бота" и включите “Возможности ботов”. https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3?f=4.1.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5